# How to automatically increment by one in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to automatically increment by one in Firebase. If the user sends a message, the data inside Firebase will be incremented by one.

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so for? Any code? Implementations and or research? Increments in Firebase are already documented several times.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FieldValue.increment()

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc('ABC123')
  .update({'count': FieldValue.increment(+1)})
```

or use [transaction](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#updating-documents)

or use [cloud trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created)