# Create Table inside table using Firebase and Xamarin Forms

Tags: firebase, xaml, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I'm learning how to use Firebase, and I came across a data storage problem.

I am creating a crud, to save contacts, however, first I create the login system and store the data in the Firebase Users table, then, within the App, after creating a contact, the created contact data is not stored within the user created within the "Users" Table, if I create 2 or more users and access the app, I can access contacts created by other users.

How I would like it to be structured:

[image]

```
public async Task<bool> RegisterUser(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        if(await UserExist(username, password))
        {
            throw new Exception("O usuário já existe");
        }

        await Client.Child("Users")
            .PostAsync(new Users()
            {
                User = username,
                Password = password,
                //I tried to create an empty list inside users to then insert the data, but I couldn't
                Contacts = new List<Contacts>()
            });
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the other Service, the one that adds the contacts, it looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> RegisterContact(string name, string telefone1, string telefone2, string email, string cep, string logradouro, string numero, string bairro, string complemento, string cidade, string uf)
{
    try
    {
        await Client.Child("Registrations")
            .PostAsync(new Contacts()
            {
                Name = name,
                Tell1 = telefone1,
                Tell2 = telefone2,
                Email = email,
                Cep = cep,
                Logradouro = logradouro,
                Numero = numero,
                Bairro = bairro,
                Complemento = complemento,
                Cidade = cidade,
                Uf = uf
            });


        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;

    }
}
```

this is my repository in github: https://github.com/SgCafe/XamarinFirebaseCRUD

I tried using .Child(username) after .Child("Users") but it didn't work

Comment: `I tried using .Child(username) after .Child("Users") but it didn't work ` Could you please post the full code?

Comment: I published the link to the github repository in the post, can you access it?

Comment: Is there the possibility of creating something like sqlite autoincrement in firebase, as I believe I need to pass the user id in the task

Comment: Please check thread : [How to automatically increment by one in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260133/how-to-automatically-increment-by-one-in-firebase).